# Anybody know how I can write a game for the dualshock 3 or other gampad in python?

Tags: python

I am a new developer and want to write a game that uses a gamepad like the dualshock 3 I want to write it in python although am willing to learn a little C/C++

I need to identify the buttons and rotaters and send feedback like haptics not to mention the motion control

Answer (score 3):

Well, SDL has support for controllers (joysticks) and pygame is a python wrapper for SDL so in theory it should support joysticks. There does seem to be support (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) for joysticks but I cannot say how well a dualshock 3 controller maps to it. (Theres some issues around mapping the Xbox 360 controller for example)

Answer (score 2):

You can: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html

Also: http://thp.io/2010/archive/joystick-gstreamer.py

Extract:
Control GStreamer filters in a pipeline using analog sticks of gamepads
Copyright (c) 2010-12-22 Thomas Perl